# Finding the basis of the sum and intersection of two spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In a vector space $\mathbb{R}^7$, those vectors which satisfy the system of equations
$$x_1-2x_4+3x_5-5x_6+4x_7=0$$
$$x_2 + x_4 - 4x_5 - x_6 - 3x_7=0$$
$$x_3 - 3x_4 - x_5 - 2x_6 + x_7 = 0$$
form a vector subspace $W_1$, and solutions to the system
$$x_1-3x_4-x_5-8x_6-x_7=0$$
$$x_2-x_4-9x_5-4x_6-4x_7=0$$
$$x_3-6x_4-7x_5-5x_6+4x_7$$
are a subspace $W_2$. I need to find a basis for $W_1$, $W_2$, $W_1 + W_2$ and $W_1 \cap W_2$. I think I have found the correct basis vectors for $W_1$ and $W_2$. For $W_1$, I get $$\{(2,-1,3,1,0,0,0),(-3,4,1,0,1,0,0),(5,1,2,0,0,1,0),(-4,3,-1,0,0,0,1)\}$$ and for $W_2$ I get $$\{(3,1,6,1,0,0,0),(1,9,7,0,1,0,0),(8,4,5,0,0,1,0),(1,4,-4,0,0,0,1)\}$$ For ease, let's call the basis vectors of $W_1$ $u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4$, and lets call the basis vectors for $W_2$ $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$. Then, I think that $W_1 + W_2$ is the set of vectors $$c_1u_1+...+c_4u_4 + c_5v_1+...+c_8v_4$$ for $c_i\in\mathbb{R}$. It's here that I get stuck. From reading some other posts on here, it seems like the next step is to put the basis vectors from $W_1$ and $W_2$ into the columns of a matrix augmented with the $0$ vector, and row reduce to find the basis vectors of $W_1 + W_2$. However, when I do this I get that $$c_1=-c_5,\\c_2=-c_6,\\c_3=-c_7,\\c_4=-c_8$$ and I don't know how to interpret this. Are my basis vectors $u_1-v_1, u_2-v_2$ etc? Futhermore, I don't know how to find the basis of $W_1 \cap W_2$, and I'm also supposed to find a set $\{a_1, a_2...a_7\}$ for $a_i\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $W_1+W_2$ is the set of solutions $x$ to the equation $$a_1x_1+a_2x_2+...+a_7x_7 = 0$$ If anyone could point me in the right direction it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is telling you that if $c_1u_1+\dots=0$, then you must have $c_1=-c_5$ etc. That is also clear by inspection, because the only $u_i$ with non-zero 4-component is $u_1$ and the only $v_i$ is $v_1$. Similarly for the other equations. So look at the 4 vectors $w_i=v_i-u_i$, which have 0s except in the first three places. It is easy to get linear combinations to give $(1,0,\dots),(0,1,0\dots),(0,0,1,\dots)$. So dim$(W_1+W_2)=7$ You can also get a linear combination of the $w_i$ which gives 0. Rearranging that a linear comb of $u_i$ equal to a lc of $v_i$, hence a basis for $W_1\cap W_2$.

Comment: I understand your argument as to why $dim(W_1 + W_2)$ is 7. However, I'd like to know a more general approach. I've seen a couple posts here suggesting that getting that matrix with columns $u_1, u_2...v_1...v_4$ into RREF, the pivot columns in the RREF suggest that the original vector in that column is a basis of $W_1 + W_2$, and that the non pivot columns suggest that the vector in that column is a basis of $W_1\cap W_2$. Is this true in general? I suppose this could perhaps warrant a seperate post.

Comment: Why augment with zero? It provides no additional information—it will remain zero regardless of the elementary row operations that you apply to the matrix.

Comment: It appears that there’s an error either in your transcription of the problem or your row-reduction of the combined matrix. The intersection of the two subspaces is actually two-dimensional, which also means that $\dim(W_1+W_2)=6$.

Comment: One way to find a basis for $W_1\cap W_2$ is to combine the two systems of equations that you’ve been given and solve them.

Comment: I think I do actually find that $dim(W_1 + W_2)=6$ and the other 2. My only question left i think is finding the $a_1...a_7$ i mentioned at the end of my post. I don’t really know what that’s looking for.

Comment: Well, you know that $W_1+W_2$ is a hyperplane (in fact, that last part of the problem is a clue that $\dim(W_1+W_2)=6$), so it’s asking you to find a linear equation with this hyperplane as its solution set. Hint: write the equation as $a\cdot x=0$.